# users wall post as application

Tags: php, facebook

[image]

I want to post message to selected user`s wall but like to customize picture and
title(name)?

is there any solution? below may be garbage...

```
    $access_token_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
    $parameters ="type=client_cred&client_id=CCCCCCC&client_secret=AA";

    $access_token = file_get_contents($access_token_url . "?" . $parameters);

    $user_facebookUID = "AAAAAAAAAA";
    $data = array();
    $data["access_token"] = $access_token;
    $data["message"] = "aadfadfsdf";

    $facebook->api("/$user_facebookUID/feed/" , "post", $param);
```

then message was posted to the users wall as an application.

but that users picture and user`s name was displayed.

but I like to customize user picture to other and change user`s name to another title.

how can it possible? isthere any other way to solve this not as application or application

Comment: Oh my, the formatting. So let me get this straight: You want to post something as a user but change their name and picture?

Comment: sorry , is there any way to post some message to users wall but like to customize that picture and title,is there any other mechanism?

Comment: I asked you a yes/no question.

Answer (score 1):

(**WARNING : HACKY SOLUTION, there is no "legal" way of doing it as stated in the other answer**) : I think the only solution is to create a facebook "user" with the picture you want and the name you want, then you would post on a user's wall but specifying the "from" field as your custom user and the "to" field as the user of your application. (So you're posting on the user's wall from another profile as if you were a friend posting on another user's wall)

See details on the post object in the graph api here : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

If you want the picture and name to change for every posting It will not be possible I think.

Comment: When you say "create a Facebook user" you mean like a "fake" user?

Comment: -1, you are aware that creating fake accounts is illegal and will get your app disabled!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer...**NO**! You can't change the user's profile picture or name.